# WCF problem passing complex type_either worked with invoke

Tags: c#, wcf, postman

I want to pass complex type ( list of integers and other integer) in my service wcf.
here is my service:

```
    [OperationContract]        
     [WebInvoke(Method = "Get", UriTemplate = "GetUserByID")]    
    List<User> GetUserByID(UserIdParams userIdParams);
```

This is my class type:

```
public class UserIdParams : CommonParams
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<int> ListUserId { get; set; }
}
```

- If I test it with WCF Test Client , it is ok ,it worked
  [image]
- but if I test it with Postman , i have error ! 
  [image]
- List item

*** The behavior :

```
 <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>  
    </behavior>
```

The XML of WCF Test Client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IServiceDataExtractor" 
  sendTimeout="00:05:00">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint 
 address="https://localhost:44310/ServiceDataExtractor.svc/soap"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IServiceDataExtractor"
            contract="IServiceDataExtractor" 
 name="BasicHttpsBinding_IServiceDataExtractor" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

So how can i fix it ?

Comment: Are you sending one User or List<User>?

Comment: No i send UserId,
in fact,i can send  both( UserId and List<int>, 
but in this exemple i send just an integer :UserId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for dnxit, he offered me a solution by always working with GET,

- My old class :

  ```
  public class UserIdParams : CommonParams
  {
  [DataMember]
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public List<int> ListUserId { get; set; }     
  }
  ```
- and the old service :

  ```
  [OperationContract]        
  [WebInvoke(Method = "Get", UriTemplate = "GetUserByID")]    
  List<User> GetUserByID(UserIdParams userIdParams);
  ```

Now for fix this bug and  work execute WCF REST with a parameter Array:
* the modified class:

```
public class UserIdParams : CommonParams
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]     
    public string DelimitedUserIds { get; set; }
}
```

- the modified service:

  ```
  [OperationContract]        
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetUserByID?DelimitedUserIds={DelimitedUserIds}")]
  List<User> GetUserByID(string DelimitedUserIds);
  ```

And the most important thing is to add : (exemple)

```
 string DelimitedUserIds = "9,3,12,43,2"
 List<int> UserIds = DelimitedUserIds .Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

WCF Test client test this operation as **SOAP service** not **rest service**.Please refer **XML tab** in test client.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've found that with the restful style of the WCF service, the Get method does not support using complex objects as parameters by default, thereby please consider using the post/put method. This also does not conform to the design guidelines for the HTTP get method.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/08/08/wcf-extensibility-querystringconverter/
In addition, Postman is usually used to test restful services.
Here is a configuration which applies on restful style WCF service.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything  I can help with.

Comment: very thanks for your reply @Abraham Qian ,
I added the solution for my problem, and still working with GET always,
you can take a look for it